# How to define functional argument with implicit parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functional-dependencies

I have a simple function, that I use to generate generic Spec2 tests:

```
def check[T <: ED](actual: Seq[T], expectedFile: File)(implicit format: Format[T], ordering: Ordering[T]): Seq[MatchResult[Any]] 


def generateCheck(clientName: String, patientId: String, folder: File)
```

Where *generateCheck* calls *check* allot. I want instead of defining check as a separate function, use it as functional argument for generateChecks

I want to have something like this:

```
def generateCheck(clientName: String, patientId: String, folder: File, check: ???)
```

For now I made a workaround, and just override check as needed, but I still wonder How can I define check as a functional argument?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I actually thought this is simple, but it is not. I am missing a bit of insights into your code, but next may give you some ideas:

I don't think you can do implicits with anonymous functions. At least I haven't seen that anywhere done. But you can easily wrap it:

```
 class Check[T]()(implicit format: Format[T]) extends ((Seq[T], File) => Unit) {
    override def apply(v1: Seq[T], v2: File): Unit = ??? // your implementation
  }
```

So:

```
    def test(check: Check[Int]): Unit = {
      check(Seq.empty, new File("."))
    }

    test(new Check[Int]())
```

Or if you can refactor the function that doesn't need implicit context (I just think having implicit class is nice here, but not sure it is applicable to your case):

```
 implicit class Check[T](val f: (Seq[T], File) => Unit)(implicit format: Format[T]) extends ((Seq[T], File) => Unit) {
    override def apply(v1: Seq[T], v2: File): Unit = f(v1, v2) //do some processing and call f
  }
```

Now:

```
  def test(check: Check[Int]): Unit = {
    check(Seq.empty, new File("."))
  }

  test((a: Seq[Int], b: File) => {
    println("Hello world")
  })
```

But you need to remember to put types into your function, or manually wrap it in `new Check[T]`

Comment: Thanks :) It's a good example, but does not apply to my case. Inside of generateCheck there are different calls with different entities - like check(a: A, f: File), check(b: B, f: File), check(c: C, f: File), so this won't work for me. And I hoped for something simpler :)

Comment: @mavarazy You could have separate `Check` implementations. Also you could avoid extending from `=>` and create a class with just a method `execute[T]` that will have your `check` implementation. Unfortunately that's the only way I can think of of how to solve your problem. There might be something much more advanced I could not think of, but I doubt you would want to move such simple problem into advanced areas like macros, usually it is needless complications

Comment: I understand the solution, but it seems like overkill for the task at hand; inheriting and overriding is much simpler to understand in this case.